# "Nix" oder "Nichts"?

Tags: word-usage, standard-german, slang, business-correspondence

Jetzt wohne ich in Bayern. Die bayrische Bevölkerung benutzt immer das Wort "nix". Ich vermute, das heißt "nichts", oder? Aber zum Beispiel in Berlin verwendet niemand "nix". Am Anfang habe ich auch "nichts" benutzt. Aber jetzt will ich "nix" ausprobieren.

Was denken Sie?
 Und was ist die beste zu verwenden?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Geht es um "welche Alltagsvokabel ist in Bayern für _nichts_ am besten"?  Oder um welchen Sprachkontext geht es? Worin besteht das eigene Problem? Zu wissen, was "die Leute" sagen oder zu verwenden, was und wie es "die Leute" verwenden? Dazu kommt, dass Bayern nicht gerade klein ist und es so manche Dialekt-Eigenschaften gibt :-o Und wenn es um "business correspondance" geht - da würde ich z.B. meine Vorgesetzte fragen, wie schlimm es ist, Hochdeutsch zu verwenden.

Comment: 'Zum Beispiel in Berlin, Sie verwenden niemals "nix".'
Bist Du Dir sicher, dass Du die beiden Aussprachen auseinander halten kannst, wenn jemand schnell spricht?

Comment: @CarstenS Ich habe nicht die Berliner gemeint, aber nur Die Bayerische.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Ich möchte wissen, ob es in ordnung ist, in einem professionellen Umfeld zu verwenden.

Comment: @VishvaDeZoysa gesprochen eher ja, es ist im bairischen Sprachraum mehr oder weniger nur eine Aussprachevariante. Geschrieben: nie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nichts** ist die korrekte Schreibweise und Aussprache, und die einzige, die im Schriftdeutsch verwendet wird, sofern nicht bewusst ein umgangssprachlicher Ton angedeutet werden soll.

Daneben gibt es verschiedene umgangssprachliche Varianten, die in unterschiedlichen Regionen in Verwendung sind und normalerweise eine gewisse Vereinfachung der Aussprache darstellen (denn auch Muttersprachler finden das Konsonantencluster "chts" mitunter zu umständlich, wenn sie schnell sprechen):

- nix
- nischt
- nischte
- nüscht

usw.

Im Atlas der Alltagssprache konnte ich zwar noch keine Erhebung zu Variationen des Wortes "nichts" finden, jedoch ist ["nicht"](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f25e/) ein ähnlicher Fall.

Comment: @Mapper Vielen vielen Dank! :)

Comment: @VishvaDeZoysa: Gerne - falls du diese Antwort als "die passende Antwort" betrachtest, benutze bitte das Häkchen, um sie als "akzeptiert" zu markieren. (Du kannst auch gerne eine Weile damit warten, damit noch weitere Nutzer potenziell bessere Antworten schreiben.)